# Checkstyle - how to setting with custom check

Tags: checkstyle

I am trying to create a custom checker using checkstyle. I'm trying to write it in code, and trying to check it using gradle. (using gradle in an existing project and want to add checkstyle). I structured it like below and wrote the code, but I can't seem to find the class well.
I am getting the following error. how can i fix it?

> Unable to instantiate 'com.example.checks.CustomCheck' class, it is
> also not possible to instantiate it as null. Please recheck that class
> name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short
> name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also
> recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.

```
project
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── com
│   │   │   │   └── example
│   │   │   │         └── app
│   │   │   │              └── MyClass.java
│   │   │             └── checks
│   │   │                  └── CustomCheck.java
│   │   
│   │ 
│   └── config
│       └── checkstyle.xml 
└── build.gradle
```

checksytle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="com.example.checks.CustomCheck"/>
    </module>
    ...
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'checkstyle'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:10.9.3'
}

checkstyle {
  toolVersion '10.9.3';
}
```

CustomCheck.java

```
package com.example.checks;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractCheck;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;

public class CustomCheck extends AbstractCheck {
   ...
}
```